# Remove columns from the data stored in the "variable"

Tags: r

So I loaded few csv files:

```
tbl = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
> tbl
 [1] "F1.csv"  "F10.csv" "F11.csv" "F12.csv" "F13.csv" "F14.csv" "F15.csv" "F16.csv"
 [9] "F17.csv" "F18.csv" "F19.csv" "F2.csv"  "F20.csv" "F3.csv"  "F4.csv"  "F5.csv" 
[17] "F6.csv"  "F7.csv"  "F8.csv"  "F9.csv"
```

And now I would like to delete two columns from the F6.csv file. Those columns are 7 and 8. 
How to delete those columns from:

```
tbl[17]
```

Can I access this data directly or I have to just load this table separately and remove those coulmns.

Comment: None of these files are loaded into R.  list.files() is listing what files are in the directory you are working in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the note above, you have to read these files into R.  Then, you can manipulate them once they're in your local environment

```
# read all of the files into R
for(i in list.files(pattern = '*.csv')){
   name <- paste(i)
   dat <- read.csv(i, header = T)
   assign(name, dat)
}

# remove columns 7 & 8 from F6.csv
F6.csv <- F6.csv[, -c(7, 8)]

# if you want to write this new data set to F6.csv
# write.csv(F6.csv, 'F6.csv', row.names = F)
```